# Why are the names of one baby separated by a comma?

Tags: commas

When surfing the web I came across this card published by the Prince & Princess of Monaco.

It mentiones the names of their twins. But why are the three names of each child separated by a comma? (My first impression was along the lines of "Six kids? huh?")

[image: Thank-you card]

Comment: Everybody in Monaco is really rich, so they don't have to go to school?

Comment: Actually, they're so rich they can afford all those extra commas.

Comment: @HotLicks and they're not just any commas. Each of those commas is hand-crafted by master artisans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the form used for names within the House of Grimaldi, or at least within the Monaco royal family.

Similarly the website of the Palais Princier de Monaco gives the name of Albert II as "Son Altesse Sérénissime le Prince Albert, Alexandre, Louis, Pierre, Prince Souverain de Monaco" in French and "His Serene Highness Prince Albert, Alexandre, Louis, Pierre, Sovereign Prince of Monaco" and similarly for the other members of the house except for Princess Charlene, who is a member by marriage.

Which isn't really anything to do with English Language and Usage, since people name their kids all manner of things according to a variety of national, regional, cultural and family traditions.

It does entail an EL&U question though; should we use the comma when giving the full name of one of these people?

Since they use the commas themselves it would definitely not be wrong to emulate that.

However, they don't seem to find the form without commas to be objectionable since that form has been [used in official announcements too](http://www.palais.mc/en/news/h-s-h-prince-albert-ii/event/2010/june/the-palace-of-monaco-announced-the-engagement-of-hsh-prince-albert-ii-of-monaco-with-ms-charlene-wittstock-1768.html), and most people use the version without commas.

As such either would be a correct form to use.

Comment: I disagree that both formats are valid. In my view, when the name of a foreign national is used by English speakers, it becomes subject to the conventions of English usage that English speakers normally apply to names — as with any loanword. The commas between the names of Albert II (but not those introducing his titles of rank) should thus be omitted, if for no other reason than that leaving them *in situ* is a conflicting, and hence confusing, usage as far as speakers of English are concerned. People's names are not exempt from the principle of the paramountcy of clarity of communication.